# MySQL inserts twice PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hey guys not looking for explanation on why its inserting twice, I understand it  loops from ['0'] to ['1'] just want to figure out how to stop my insert after the first try...

```
$trans=array('hello' => 'allo',
             'bye' => 'salut'), 
$sql = "INSERT INTO trans (en, fr) values ";    
$valuesArr = array();
foreach ($trans as $key => $value){
    $en = mysql_real_escape_string( $key );
    $fr = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    $valuesArr[] = "('$en', '$fr')";
}

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
```

My actual question is can i stop the foreach as soon as it goes through the array using break;?

Comment: "'bye' => 'salut')," - syntax error - no semicolon, you have colon instead

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` shouldn't be used in new code because it's been deprecated, is dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a number of recommendations as to how to keep your application up-to-date.

Comment: not legacy just trying to save old array in db, wanna automate it for a one time run. Still havnt figure out my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a counter to control the building of your insert - assuming you want the 2nd of the 2 inserts

```
$trans=array('hello' => 'allo','bye' => 'salut');
$sql = "INSERT INTO trans (en, fr) values ";    
$valuesArr = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($trans as $key => $value){

    if ($i > 0) {
        $en = mysql_real_escape_string( $key );
        $fr = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
        $valuesArr[] = "('$en', '$fr')";
    }
    $i++;

}

$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
```

Comment: i only want the inital

Comment: By making $i = 1 it stop at the first and resolved my issue Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is inserting two rows at one time (it isn't inserting twice as you mentioned) because your `$trans` array contains two items which are iterating in `foreach` loop. After the `foreach` loop the `$valuesArr` is equal to:

```
[0] => ('hello', 'allo')
[1] => ('bye', 'salut')
```

Then you are using `implode` to join `$valuesArr` elements with comma as separator and concat with `$sql` variable which produce final SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO trans(en, fr) values ('hello', 'allo'),('bye', 'salut')
```

I think I don't need to explain what this query do.